# Is there an event to capture the HTML Slider element's as soon as the value changes on slider [Issue with MenloSecurity]

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, dom-events

We have an case where we listen to `Change` event of a Slider element and it captures well on normal browsers. However, when using with our Org's security layer (safe.menlosecurity appended on front of URLs), on those case, the change event is not captured, unless a click is made outside the element. Strangely, when the slider is controlled with the keyboard's navigation controls, then they are fired immediately on both the browsers. Kindly advice if anyone has faced such issues with Security browsers.

I tried other alternative events such as `input`, `mouseup` but they are not applicable as they tend to miss the updated values on the slider.